# iOS map annotation, whole annotation clickable?

Tags: ios7

I have a map annotation that has an "(i)" callout accessory that pushes in a view when clicked. The customer has asked that the entire annotation be a hit target, not just the callout. Is there an easy way to get taps on any part of the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this MKMapViewDelegate method?

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

Comment: Yes, but this event fires when you click on the pin, not the "bubble view" that has been created by clicking on the pin. I know that tap is going to the bubble view, but I can't figure out how to easily capture it in the base map view like the event you just posted.

Comment: Ah ok, I do present the annotationView in code and therefore this method is called on the tap of the bubble view, but not in case of going throught the pin first. I would then add a gesture recognizer on the bubble view (in `viewForAnnotation:`) and act on the gesture delegate call.

Comment: Ok I think I understand; I can add the gesture to the View, then send a message - perhaps even the same one as the callout? - to the delegate, which is the map view. Is that basically it?

Comment: Yes. But I would let the recognizer call a separate method, because you need to get a reference to the annotationView that called. You use selector similar to this: `- (void)callOutTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
` and you can then retrieve the view that was tapped from `recognizer.view` property and continue where you need to.